# How do you change the default background color for menustrips and menus in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, menu

These days with Visual C# (Visual C# 2008 specifically) it seems that the default color for menustrips and menus is blue, which to me looks really strange and is something that I'd really like to override. I'm guessing that Visual Studio is picking up this blue color from my selected system theme or something, however no other Windows app running on my system has this blue color so I don't know why my .NET apps would have to have it. ;)

Anyway, I noticed that if I create an application using an older version of Visual Studio (Visual Studio.NET), the default background color for menustrips and menus is the standard gray that you'd expect to see. This is one solution to the problem I suppose, but it seems like kind of a stupid one and I'd really like to find a way to override it in the current version of Visual C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DotNet 1.x didn't have a MenuStrip, and used a standard Windows menu.

DotNet versions 2.0 and up have the MenuStrip, and VS 7 and up removes the MainMenu from the toolbox and replaces it with a MenuStrip, which uses the Office <del>Xp</del> 2003 theme, hence the blue color scheme for the MenuStrip and ToolStrip.

The MainMenu can still be added to the toolbox for a standard Windows menu.

Answer (score 11):

Set the "**RenderMode**" option of the MenuStrip to "**System**" instead of "managerRenderMode"

:)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting the back color of your menuStrip? You should be able to do something like:

```
this.menuStrip1.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
```

Comment: That works for the menustrip, but not for the gradient on the menus or for the highlight color on the menustrip.

Answer (score 3):

For C# .Net

To add to "magnusi" response I was able to achieve the menu style I have been wanting for a while now. Many thanks. I have added the minimum Render Targets needed to achieve this look.

[image]

<strike>**note** Visual Studio will remove your Custom MyRender reference call from the Designer.cs file every time you update or change your menu items or form contents. I would recommend creating your project in its entirety and then add your MyRender Class to the Designer.cs or just remember to add it back in.</strike>
"rory.ap" "put it in your constructor below InitializeComponent();"

Designer.cs (edited)

```
 public TCP_Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // My Renderer
        this.menuStrip1.Renderer = new My_Render();
    }
```

I have notated the Render Targets the best I could. Also when you create your class you have to add " : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer " next to it to access the Render Targets.

MyRender.cs

```
internal class MyRender : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer 
{
    public MyRender() : base(new MyColorTable()) { }
}

public class MyColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the starting color of the gradient used when 
    /// a top-level System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem is pressed.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin => Color.DimGray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the end color of the gradient used when a top-level 
    /// System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem is pressed.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd => Color.DimGray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the border color to use with a 
    /// System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color MenuItemBorder => Color.DarkGray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the starting color of the gradient used when the 
    /// System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem is selected.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin => Color.Silver;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the end color of the gradient used when the 
    /// System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem is selected.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd => Color.DimGray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the solid background color of the 
    /// System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground => Color.DimGray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the starting color of the gradient used in the image 
    /// margin of a System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownMenu.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin => Color.DimGray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the middle color of the gradient used in the image 
    /// margin of a System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownMenu.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientMiddle => Color.DimGray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the end color of the gradient used in the image 
    /// margin of a System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownMenu.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd => Color.DimGray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the color to use to for shadow effects on 
    /// the System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color SeparatorDark => Color.Black;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the color that is the border color to use 
    /// on a System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip.
    /// </summary>
    public override Color MenuBorder => Color.DarkGray;
}
```

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can make own Renderer

```
    public class BrowserMenuRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public BrowserMenuRenderer() : base(new BrowserColors()) {}
}
public class BrowserColors : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30); }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemBorder
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30); }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30); }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30); }
    }
}
```

Then you just set your menustrip's renderer as YourRenderer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the render mode but that only sets the system theme to default.  .net allows you to change the backcolor and the for color but when you hover over it It still shows the default colors.
Heres a way around that...

his is very simple to accomplish by using the "DropDownOpening" , "DropDownClosed", and "MouseEnter" events.

```
private void fileToolStripMenuItem_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e){

    // When the user clicks on "File" it will change to red.
    fileToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

```
private void testToolStripMenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e){

    // When the user hovers over a child of "file" called "test", "file" turns orange.
    fileToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
}
```

```
private void test2ToolStripMenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e){

    // When the user hovers on a child of "file" called "test2", "file" turns blue.
    fileToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

```
private void fileToolStripMenuItem_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e){

    // When the user leaves the "file" menu, it gets restored back to black.
    fileToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```